# Cannot connect to L-VAIO\sqlexpress

Tags: sql-server

I installed SQL Server 2008 R2 the other day to work with Visual Studio 2010 pro.

I was able to use SQL Server fine until this morning. I loaded up SQL Server Management Studio and I get the following error:

> Cannot connect to L-VAIO\sqlexpress
>
> A network-related or instance-specific
>   error occurred while establishing a
>   connection to SQL Server. The server
>   was not found or was not accessible.
>   Verify that the instance name is
>   correct and that SQL Server is
>   configured to allow remote
>   connections. (provider: SQL Network
>   Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating
>   Server/Instance Specified) (Microsoft
>   SQL Server, Error: -1)

If I also load up Visual Studio 2010 I also cannot now get into my database.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Is the SQL Server service up and running? Is this really  `.\SQLExpress` instance, or the full product?? Can you connect to `(local)` (without the .\SQLExpress) ??

Comment: Solved:  My server was disabled :/

Comment: "I installed SQL Server 2008 R2" doesn't sound like you installed the Express edition.

Comment: @Richard there is a R2 version of express ;-)

Comment: @Phil: Thanks. :-P He didn't say "Express" though, so I just thought maybe . . .

Comment: It say SQL Server 2008 R2 when you load it.  I assume its the free version as Ive not purchased any price versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like it can't find the server, check the service for SQL Server is running. Sometimes I find that it doesn't start properly.

Press the start button and type Services. Scroll down and look for the SQL Server instance service, should be something like: SQL Server (Instance).

@philjones88

Comment: Yes I should have checked that first before posting, doh. :)